# How to open text links in magnific-popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

On my [web page](http://boreas.com.hr/VivoSomnia/test_afl/index.html), on "PROJECT" section (first photo), I don't know how to make the magnific popup to open links rather than not zoom pictures.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your website you have a `scripts.js` file. Remove or comment lines going from 22 to 45. Those lines contains the code that runs the `magnificPopup` jQuery plugin.